# iframe will not center on the page on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe for a third party site plugin (Salon Iris) that isn't playing nice. The iframe is called via javascript and will not center on the middle of the page on desktop. On mobile it stacks nicely. The only way I can get it to center is wrapping it in a DIV and applying styles but that breaks the mobile functionality since I have to apply a width parameter.

I've tried using a media query to remove the styles (for centering) from the DIV on mobile but it doesn't seem to respond.

JS calling iframe:

```
<div class="saloniris" id="contact">

<script type="text/javascript">daysmart_acc = "6c9943df-39d6-4444-b786-8109d2b732f6"; daysmart_iframe_width = 900; daysmart_iframe_height = 0; </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://plugin.mysalononline.com/Scripts/external/bookingplugin.js"></script>

</div>
```

http://www.stylehouse.nickolasbarnes.com/#contact

Comment: iFrame hv `align` attribute did u try `align="center"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider adding an auto margin and display properties to your iframe style?

```
iframe{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

should solve it for you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jo9sn52f/)

Comment: Beat me to it.  So long as you don't need adjacent content, this answer is your best bet.

Comment: This did not work for me. My hunch is that it has something to do with it being called by JS? I wrapped it in a DIV and applied what you suggested above

Comment: EDIT: I misunderstood what you wrote. I applied the properties you suggested to the iframe style in my stylesheet and still no change. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show the code of your page,  it will be easier for me to take it from there. My assumption is that some other CSS is probably overwriting these properties.